# How to set the location of an EditText in Java code

Tags: android, user-interface

How do you set the location or bounds of an EditText? I want to do it through my Java code, not in the XML (layout) file. Is there a way to set the location? I'm usually a pro at GUI things but this has never come up before, so any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't explicitly set the position of a View in Android like setViewPos(x,y).

Do you know how the android layout/view system works? If you can achieve what you're trying to do in XML, then just look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html and see what setter method corresponds to the XML attributes you're using.

If your view already exists in XML and you want to do stuff to it at runtime then you need to reference it. In the trivial case, you're in your activity and you're modifying a view that's in your current layout:

```
EditText yourView = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.your_view);    
//set attributes 
//you'll crash if you haven't this.setContentView(view's parent layout)
```

Otherwise:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View tmp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null , true);
EditText yourView = (EditText)tmp.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
//set attrinutes
```

or if you're creating your view from scratch, just make an instance of it and add it your layout:

```
EditText et= new EditTExt();
//set attributes
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
parent.addView(et)
```

But if you don't know how to position it in XML either, you'll have to take a trip down tutorial alley to find the technique that suits your situation.

AbsoluteLayout would be a quick fix but I wouldn't suggest it because you'll get some nasty results when you try your app on phones with different screens sizes and resolutions.

The gravity and weight are not as powerful but they are not hard linked to the screen size.

If you're trying to place you view based on the views surrounding it, then definitely use 
RelativeLayout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, i knew i could do it in XML but i thought for sure i could do it in Android also but i wasn't sure how, i guess ill just redo the layout in XML and fix it up from there. Thanks!